# Can't validate editable h2 tag in the jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I want to change and validate the value of html's h2 tag. I have placed it in a div. What current scenario is when i press h2 tag, it automatically opens a text box and I can edit/clear the value of text box.

**Issue:** When I try to empty text box value then it does not generating error message at run time. But error message generates when i click my jsp file. Here is a sample code.

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h2 class="tc_pageheader editableName" id="detailsheader"></h2>
</div>
```

In my case, when id value is empty then it must display an error message that h2 tag cannot be empty. I want to achieve this by validation by using jQuery (v1.9).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here's a tip for getting good answers: provide _relevant_ code. If you require help with the validation code, post the validation code :)

Comment: Please add your jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there isn't much code to go on, I made a mock up of what I think you're trying to do.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NnkRV/

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#detailsheader', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='edit' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
});

$(document).on('focusout', '#edit', function() {
    var newTitle = this.value;
    if (newTitle == '') {
        alert("Cant be blank!");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $(this).replaceWith('<h2 class="tc_pageheader editableName" id="detailsheader">' + newTitle + '</h2>');
    }
});
```

This just lets you edit the title of the H2, displays an error if there is a blank title.